# Rename FileNames Using Concatenation

Tags: excel, vba, filenames

I currently have an excel spreadsheet that has the following output

```
Old_Name               PlayerID        PlayerName
20190324181982.MTS      1               Jake Smith
20190324181963.MTS      2               Greg Johnson
20190324181923.MTS      3               Jake De Maria
```

The "Old Name" Column keeps track of the video files I upload to my computer. I have attempted VBA code (see below) that identifies the "Old Name" in the stored folder and changes it to playerid + playername. For example, 1Jake Smith.

```
Sub autofilename()
    Dim dca As Workbook
    Dim checklist As Worksheet
    Dim oldfilepath As String
    Dim old_name As String
    Dim playerid As String
    Dim playername As String
    Dim lastrow As Integer

    Set dca = ActiveWorkbook
    Set checklist = dca.Sheets("Venezuela_list")
    lastrow = checklist.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    oldfilepath = "C:\Users\nhwal\Docs\Practice"

    For a = 2 To lastrow
        old_name = checklist.Cells(a, 1).Value
        playerid = checklist.Cells(a, 2).Value
        playername = checklist.Cells(a, 3).Value

        On Error Resume Next
        Name old_name & old_name As old_name & playerid & playername & " MTS.url"
    Next a
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, the code I tried does not change the names of my files. Does anyone know how to adjust my code to get the files to change names? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `old_name`? You are using variables `old_name, playerid and playername` but you have not declared or set them anywhere   **[1]** Use `Option Explicit` **[2]** Remove `On Error Resume Next` and properly handle the error. Unnecessary use of `On Error Resume Next` is like telling the application to `Shut the $%#% up` :)

Comment: Note that row counting variables need to be of type `Long` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle: `Dim lastrow As Long`

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I don't think I've ever seen a explanation for implementing `Option Explicit` quite so succinctly.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. That was a typo on my end. I have made the appropriate edits both with the declared variables and the `dim lastrow` but still no luck

Comment: Why `old_name & old_name` and not `oldfilepath & "\" & old_name`? How will the code know where is the file? Similarly for `old_name & playerid & playername`... Read up on how `Name` works... BTW you still have `On Error Resume Next` :D

Answer (score 0):

You could t try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub trst()

    Dim Row As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim FileLocation As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change Workbook / Sheet names

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        FileLocation = "C:\Users\nhwal\Docs\Practice\"

        For Row = 2 To LastRow
            Name FileLocation & .Range("A" & Row).Value As FileLocation & .Range("A" & Row).Value & " " & .Range("B" & Row).Value & " " & .Range("C" & Row).Value & " MTS.url"
        Next Row

    End With

End Sub
```